# Move home second user to another disk

Tags: home-directory, drive, mountpoint

I have got three hard discs.
Ubuntu 20.04 installed on the SSD disc.
I have moved the home of user1 to sdb1. That works.
How do I make the homedir of user2 point to sdc1?

fstab:

`UUID=uudi-sda1 /   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=224F-0AB8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile  none            swap    sw              0       0
# move home
UUID=uudi-sdb1  /home   ext4    defaults     0  2`

Comment: Did you move all of `/home` or just `home/user1`?

Comment: Move the /home/user2 anywhere to sdc1. Then create a softlink at /home named user2 and pointing to the location on sdc1

Comment: Better use a bind mount than symlink. I don't remember exactly now what was it, but I stumbled upon some software that didn't work properly if user's home directory was a symlink.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I moved all of `/home`

Comment: I did:

`sudo mkdir /mnt/user2`
`sudo cp -R /home/user2/* /mnt/user2`
renamed `/home/user2`  map to `/home/user2_Old`
`sudo ln -s /mnt/user2 /home/user2`
chown of the symlink and target map to user2
Added to fstab: `UUID=uudi-sdc1  /mnt/user2   ext4    defaults     0  2`
`sudo mount -a`

Now it is working